# Como chamar função pelo onfocus e adicionar um valor em uma variavel php?

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de chamar uma função do JS quando entro em focus em algum campo do html! Mas o código não chama a função!! Como fazer?

Exemplo:

```
        <html>
            <input type="text" name="tx_nome_usua" onfocus="minhaFunc(this.name)" value="" >
        <input name="tx_rg_usua" onfocus="minhaFunc(this.name)">
        </html>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function minhaFunc(nome){
           switch(nome){
            case tx_nome_usua :
                <?php  $j = 1;?>
            break;
            case tx_rg_usua :
                <?php  $j = 3;?>
            break;
    alert(<?$j?>);
        }
        }
        </script>
```

É possível atribuir um valor a uma variável do php dessa maneira?

Comment: Com a sua edição, a pergunta mudou bastante...

Comment: Usando o PHP daquela forma que você pôs, ele nunca será executado, porque o PHP é executado no servidor, ou seja, ele é executado quando você carrega a página e não quando a função do javascript é chamada.  Para você setar uma variável num php por javascript, você precisará fazer uma chamada Ajax, e dentro do arquivo php chamado por ajax, você seta o que precisa setar, tendo em mente que as variáveis do PHP não são globais, então você precisará salvar isso em $_SESSION para conseguir ler em outro local depois.